# How to get user's albums id using facebook sdk in iOS

Tags: ios, facebook

I m using Facebook SDK version 4.16 and working on iOS 9.3

```
FBSDKGraphRequest *request = [[FBSDKGraphRequest alloc]
                                           initWithGraphPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/%@/albums",[result objectForKey:@"id"]]
                                           parameters:@{@"fields":@"albums"}
                                           HTTPMethod:@"GET"];


[request startWithCompletionHandler:^(FBSDKGraphRequestConnection *connection,
                                                   id result,
                                                   NSError *error) {
                 if (!error) {
                     NSLog(@"%@",result); // got success message
                 }
             }];
```

I did set `"user_photos"` in permission at the time of user Facebook login.
In above code `[result objectForKey:@"id"]` this line gives Facebook user id. 
but this code returns me an empty array for key data hence i am not getting album id and other details.